# Comment traduire « (software) package » en français ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, informatique

Comment peut on traduire le mot *package* (dans le sens informatique du terme) en français ? Apparemment on ne peut pas dire *paquet*.

Comment: est-ce que tu parles d'un package dans le sens `library`? Un fichier avec des fonctions que tu peux réutiliser dans ton code `main`? si c'est le cas, on utilise `librairie`ou `module`, on peut aussi utiliser directement l'anglais `package`

Comment: Oui package dans le sens de "library" en effet, merci !

Comment: je vais en faire une réponse ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Je vais parler de ce que je connais, dans le domaine de la programmation, à savoir `package`dans le sens de fichier qui regroupe des fonctions/classes

On peut utiliser différents mots:

> librairie 
>   package (prononcé à l'anglaise donc) 
>   module 
>   bibliothèque

J'en oublie peut-être mais ce sont les termes que j'ai rencontré le plus fréquemment

Answer (score 2):

Il est certainement des contextes (droit, sports...) dans lesquels on préférera avantageusement *ensemble* ou encore *forfait* mais... pour ce qui est de l'informatique... :

Pourquoi s'ennuyer à chercher autre chose qu'un mot qui a son entrée dans les dictionnaires. (au moins le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/package/57194) ) ?

Answer (score 2):

Package a plusieurs sens en informatique.

Ce peut être un groupe de fonctions/classes regroupées en bibliothèques (ex: [java](https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/26832-apprenez-a-programmer-en-java/21583-les-packages)), ou un groupe cohérent de fichiers apportant des fonctionnalités à un système d'exploitation (Unix, Linux).

On parle souvent de package (prononcé « pakèdge » [pakɛdj]), mais quand le mot est traduit, c'est soit [paquet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paquet_(logiciel)), soit paquetage.

Progiciel, déjà évoqué, est rarement l'équivalent de package. Même si un progiciel peut parfois être fourni sous la forme d'un package, la plupart des packages ne sont pas des progiciels.

Answer (score 1):

In view of the suggestions given here

https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/software+package.html

I believe that the propper tanslation is **progiciel**.

The following link

https://www.vdn.fr/actualites/conseils-informatique/difference-logiciel-progiciel/

is useful to make the difference between logiciel et progiciel.

In brief, Mathematica, for instance, is a computer algrebraic system that has thousands of built-in functions and its own programming language. This is a logiciel.

[Wolfram's](http://www.wolfram.com/) stuff or individuals have created packages for specific purposes (e.g. tensor algebra and analysis, enchanched graphical capabilities, finite element analysis, etc.) based on Mathematica's built-in functions 
or/end user-defined functions. This is progiciel.

Comment: And next time... use *Scilab* in your examples... ;)

Comment: @aCOSwt Tu as raison:-)! Un logiciel super développé et maintenu par INRIA (en France) je crois.

Comment: Et surtout... open-source ! ;)

Comment: C'est ça:-)! Par contre Mathematica (ou bien Maple) est un outil indispensable pour des calculs symboliques. Ni Python, ni Octave, ni Scilab, ni encore Matlab n'ont de telles aptitudes. SageMath (open-source) est un bon alternatif.

Answer (score 1):

Dans la programmation « Latex » un certain nombre d'auteurs traduisent ce qui est appelé en américain « package » tout simplement par « package »; voir par exemple « Latex pour l'impatient » (H&K, 4ième édition, 2016), par exemple voir la page 37.